# Unable to save app as default launcher when making outbound calls from other apps (i.e Google Maps/Browser)

Tags: android

The issue is "Unable to save app as default launcher when making outbound calls from other apps (i.e Google Maps/Browser) in Android OS version >= 4.4"

How to reproduce the issue:
steps:
a. tap the phone number with hyperlink on the browser, and then the system will show a dialog for user to select one of the apps.
b. user select one of apps from the list for example 'Skype', and select 'always' button.
c. go to a to c steps.

Anyone can help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go and check out [this forum post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1sfic2/why_does_android_make_me_constantly_select_my/):

There are many users complaining about this issue maybe you have some weird apps on your phone but a definitive solution doesn't exists right now.

I think there will be an update from google to all users having this issue.